# SQL Server error with UPDATE in column Always Encrypted

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm implementing in a `SQL Server` database the `Always Encrypted` which serves to encrypt columns of a table.

The process of creating the certificate, linking it in a table/cokuna and using it in `SQL Server Management Studio` is ok.

## Problem

When trying to `UPDATE` the column that has been encrypted, an error is occurring.

##### SQL

```
update CLIENTE set CL_CGCCPF = '11111111111*' where CL_ENCODIGO = 34
```

##### Error

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Operand type clash: varchar is
> incompatible with varchar(8000) encrypted with (encryption_type =
> 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
> 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
> 'CertificadoTeste', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'LGPD')
> collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI'

Comment: Use parameters, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210812/always-encrypted-how-to-insert-or-update-encrypted-columns. But you should be using parameters anyway.

Comment: @Charlieface Can't use conventional `UPDATE`? Because I have an application in `Delphi` that accesses the database and it would be complicated to change the SQL to update these fields that have `Always Encrypted`

Comment: A parameterized `UPDATE` is *conventional* (conforming to convention), concatenating/interpolating data into a query is *unconventional*. Why mix code and data?

Comment: @Charlieface I did not understand. What happens today is that my application does the conventional `UPDATE`. Is there any way to use the conventional `UPDATE`?

Comment: No you cannot, because you are passing data to the server as text, and the server does not have access to the encryption/decryption method, so it cannot use it. You *must* do the encryption client-side